# How to efficiently save Drawables Locally?

Tags: android, api

I am extracting Drawables like this:

```
List<ResolveInfo> appsList;
appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER),0);
```

And then:

```
    Drawable drawableIcon;
    Bitmap icon;
    File file;
    ResolveInfo ri;
    for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) {
        ri = appsList.get(i);
        drawableIcon = ri.loadIcon(pm);

        //METHOD to convert Drawable to Bitmap
        icon=drawableToBitmap(drawableIcon);
        try {
            file=new File(context.getFilesDir(),ri.activityInfo.packageName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and I am retrieving and setting the image as such:

```
        someView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(context.getFilesDir()+"/"+cachingClass.appsList.get(position).activityInfo.packageName));
```

where

> position

is a varying integer,

> someView

is an ImageView

1. Though it is working fine, but Somehow I am looking for a way to
   Directly save Drawables without having them converted to Bitmap, and
   then using `someView.setImageDrawable()` instead.
2. Can I do it with serializable way,if yes, is it a good idea?
3. `getFilesdir(),getCacheDir()` or SQLite or any other. What would be the fastest way to save and retrieve, on assumption of 50-200 images of size 2-10 KB;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Somehow I am looking for a way to Directly save Drawables without having them converted to Bitmap

You cannot persist a `Drawable`. `Drawable` is an interface.

> Can I do it with serializable way

It is possible that some implementations of `Drawable` are `Serializable`.

> is it a good idea?

I doubt that it will work, let alone work reliably. You are certainly welcome to experiment with it, though.

> What would be the fastest way to save and retrieve

I would start by not saving. I fail to see what value you are getting out of writing this stuff to disk in the first place, considering that your copy can become out of date at any point (e.g., app updates). When you need the icon, get it from the `PackageManager`.

If you feel that saving these images to disk is necessary, simple disk I/O, as you are doing, should be faster than SQLite transactions.